# Splitting comma-separated data from cell into multiple new rows without duplicating data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a list of data with thousands of entries that I need to import to a management system for a google sheets file.
Currently I have something like this:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dermazone | Medical Center | Dermal, laser hair removal, massage |
| 2 | 3Dental | Clinic | Orthodontics, General Practitioner, Prosthodontics |

I want to achieve something like this:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dermazone | Medical Center | Dermal |
| 2 |  |  | Laser Hair Removal |
| 3 |  |  | Massage |
| 4 | 3Dental | Clinic | Orthodontics |
| 5 |  |  | General Practitioner |
| 6 |  |  | Prosthodontics |

I have researched around and I found this script

```
function result(range) {
  var splitCol = 1; // split on column B
  var output2 = [];
  for(var i=0, iLen=range.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    var s = range[i][splitCol].split("\n");    
    for(var j=0, jLen=s.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      var output1 = []; 
      for(var k=0, kLen=range[0].length; k<kLen; k++) {
        if(k == splitCol) {
          output1.push(s[j]);
        } else {
          output1.push(range[i][k]);
        }
      }
      output2.push(output1);
    }    
  }
  return output2;
}
```

However I have two issues:

1. I don't want duplicate entries for other data in the row (I only want my C column to be split into new rows)
2. This script doesn't work for a lot of data (I have around 12k rows to apply this to)

Please assist me in solving these issues, I appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

From your script, I thought that you might want to use the function as the custom function. So, in this modification, please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and put a custom function of `=result(A1:C2)` to a cell.

```js
function result(values) {
  return values.flatMap(([a, b, c]) => c.split(",").map((e, i) => i == 0 ? [a, b, e.trim()] : [null, null, e.trim()]));
}
```

- If you want to use this script by running with the script editor, please use the following script.

  ```
    function result() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set the source sheet name.
      var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2"); // Please set the destination sheet name.
      var values = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      var res = values.flatMap(([a, b, c]) => c.split(",").map((e, i) => i == 0 ? [a, b, e.trim()] : [null, null, e.trim()]));
      dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
    }
  ```

#### Testing:

When the above script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Reference:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thanks! That table was just an example as I have a lot of columns. If I want to map a different column I replace a b c only? What is e for?

Comment: function result() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("complete_data_uae"); 
    var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet4"); 
    var values = srcSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    var res = values.flatMap(([a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o]) => o.split(",").map((q, i) => i == 0 ? [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o.trim()] : [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, o.trim()]));
    dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
  }

Comment: Basically, the data I want to trim is on "O" Column, will the above code work?

Comment: @Yamen Zakhour Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply. My answer is to your showing question. But, from your reply, your showing question is different from your actual question?

Comment: It's basically the same question but different columns, so basically I want to split column O instead of C, how would the script be?

Comment: @Yamen Zakhour Thank you for replying. From `It's basically the same question but different columns, so basically I want to split column O instead of C, how would the script be?`, in this case, please modify `values.flatMap(([a, b, c]) => c.split(",").map((e, i) => i == 0 ? [a, b, e.trim()] : [null, null, e.trim()]))` to `values.flatMap(([a, b, ...o]) => o[12].split(",").map((e, i) => i == 0 ? [a, b, e.trim()] : [null, null, e.trim()]))`. And, test it again.

Comment: Okay that works perfectly, thank you very much.
One more concern though, my formula is =result(complete_data_uae!2:12298) and as you can see there are many rows, so it shows me "Error: Results too large". Any way to bypass this?

Comment: @Yamen Zakhour Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `"Error: Results too large"`, so, I added one more sample script. Please test my one more sample script by modifying `var res = values.flatMap(([a, b, c]) => c.split(",").map((e, i) => i == 0 ? [a, b, e.trim()] : [null, null, e.trim()]));` to `var res = values.flatMap(([a, b, ...o]) => o[12].split(",").map((e, i) => i == 0 ? [a, b, e.trim()] : [null, null, e.trim()]));`. And test the script. In this case, please run the script with the script editor instead of the custom function.

Comment: @Yamen Zakhour When you use my added script, please remove `function result(values) {,,,}` of the custom function and run the script. Because when the same function names are used, the script cannot be correctly worked. Please be careful this.

Comment: @Yamen Zakhour Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.